# Including .xml file to rails and using it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

So I have this currency .xml file:

http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Now, I am wondering, how can I make my rails application read it? Where do I even have to put it and how do I include it?
I am basically making a currency exchange rate calculator.

And I am going to make the dropdown menu have the currency names from the .xml table appear in it and be usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're going to have to be able to read the file--I assume you want the very latest from that site, so you'll be making an HTTP request (otherwise, just store the file anywhere in your app and read it with `File.read` with a relative path). Here I use `Net::HTTP`, but you could use `HTTParty` or whatever you prefer.

It looks like it changes on a daily basis, so maybe you'll only want to make one HTTP request every day and cache the file somewhere along with a timestamp.

Let's say you have a directory in your application called `rates` where we store the cached xml files, the heart of the functionality could look like this (kind of clunky but I want the behaviour to be obvious):

```
def get_rates
  today_path = Rails.root.join 'rates', "#{Date.today.to_s}.xml"

  xml_content = if File.exists? today_path
                  # Read it from local storage
                  File.read today_path
                else
                  # Go get it and store it!
                  xml = Net::HTTP.get URI 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'
                  File.write today_path, xml
                  xml
                end

  # Now convert that XML to a hash. Lots of ways to do this, but this is very simple xml.
  currency_list = Hash.from_xml(xml_content)["Envelope"]["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"]

  # Now currency_list is an Array of hashes e.g. [{"currency"=>"USD", "rate"=>"1.3784"}, ...]
  # Let's say you want a single hash like "USD" => "1.3784", you could do a conversion like this
  Hash[currency_list.map &:values]
end
```

The important part there is `Hash.from_xml`. Where you have XML that is essentially key/value pairs, this is your friend. For anything more complicated you will want to look for an XML library like `Nokogiri`. The `["Envelope"]["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"]` is digging through the hash to get to the important part.

Now, **you can see how sensitive this will be** to any changes in the XML structure, and you should make the endpoint configurable, and that hash is probably small enough to cache up in memory, but this is the basic idea.

To get your list of currencies out of the hash just say `get_rates.keys`.

As long as you understand what's going on, you can make that smaller:

```
def get_rates
  today_path = Rails.root.join 'rates', "#{Date.today.to_s}.xml"

  Hash[Hash.from_xml(if File.exists? today_path
                       File.read today_path
                     else
                       xml = Net::HTTP.get URI 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'
                       File.write today_path, xml
                       xml
                     end)["Envelope"]["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"].map &:values]
end
```

If you do choose to cache the xml you will probably want to automatically clear out old versions of the cached XML file, too. If you want to cache other conversion lists consider a naming scheme derived automatically from the URI, e.g. `eurofxref-daily-2013-10-28.xml`.

**Edit:** let's say you want to cache the converted xml in memory--why not!

```
module CurrencyRetrieval
  def get_rates
    if defined?(@@rates_retrieved) && (@@rates_retrieved == Date.today)
      @@rates
    else
      @@rates_retrieved = Date.today
      @@rates = Hash[Hash.from_xml(Net::HTTP.get URI 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')["Envelope"]["Cube"]["Cube"]["Cube"].map &:values]
    end
  end
end
```

Now just `include CurrencyRetrieval` wherever you need it and you're golden. `@@rates` and `@@rates_retrieved` will be stored as class variables in whatever class you include this module within. You must test that this persists between calls in your production setup (otherwise fall back to the file-based approach or store those values elsewhere).

Note, if the XML structure changes, or the XML is unavailable today, you'll want to invalidate `@@rates` and handle exceptions in some nice way...better safe than sorry.

Comment: Will I be able to call the currencys now with just currency_list? I am still using the first example you gave, trying to study it :) I mean..  will I be able to for instance use it in a select_tag ?  currently I have this line there: options_for_select(@currency_list, :currency)

Comment: But this gives me a error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Have never used the select_tag before, getting used to it. But the idea is to get the names of currencys to appear in there.

Comment: Also, why is it needed to use two @'s when you put it all into a module?

Comment: In your controller action, you would set `@currency_list = get_rates`. You can log this to make sure you are getting some results by calling `Rails.logger.debug @currency_list` immediately afterwards. Then in your view, you should be able to use `select_tag(:currencies, options_for_select(@currency_list))` without a problem.

Comment: The @@ prefix causes the variables to become class variables. This means that they will be set at the class level--not the instance level. So let's say you `include CurrencyRetrieval` in ApplicationController, it means every instance of anything inheriting from ApplicationController (all your controllers, probably) will have access to the same cached list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time to answer this! I will attempt to study this now more closely.

Comment: Would you know how to also call out later the sign of the currency from the hash? If i have this number_to_currency(@arv, unit: "",
the unit: option should understand what option has been chosen from dropdown menu and then take the :currency of that option and put it in there. But if I try it like that, It does not work :S (unit: "" is just for illustration.)

Comment: I don't totally get what you mean (if this is in client side or view code) It might be best to pose a second question with just this. If you have a map of currency names to symbols it should be simple to look up that map using the text of the current option (not the value as this will be the conversion rate for that currency, e.g 1.317 not 'USD'). You could encode it as an HTML attribute on the option when you are building up that select--the options_for_select is pretty flexible if you look up the docs.